# The inherited c 'abstract' methods to be check also on other inherited clases, not only on child

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, inheritance

The example is from Django, but is a Python question.
I have an abstract class(mixin):

```
class AView(ABC):

      # @abstractmethod - comment just to explain
      def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
```

inherited as a Mixin by another class:

```
class BView(Base, Aron, DetailView, AView):
   ...
```

In this abstract class I call a method `get_context_data`

The `get_context_data` needs to be declared at least on one of BView, Aron, DetailView.

If I declared/decorate the method '@abstractmethod' it is mandatory to be on BView, otherwise I receive an error.

It is any possibility to check also the other inherited classes ?

Comment: What's the point of this? DetailView will always define `get_context_data`.

Comment: Off course DetailView implements it in the example, but Aview doesn't know what BView is inheriting. The IDE/linting show me errors because AView doesn't have a direct parent that have get_context_data when I call super(). It works in Python because it is called from DetailView, but I'm thinking maybe is a better method.

Comment: What you do is correct and perfectly valid python. Unfortunately, most IDEs won't recognise that and will give a warning (some do if you add the `Mixin` word to the name of the class). However, to be correct, you would normally exchange the order of `DetailView` and `AView` in the declaration of `BView`.